# AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance launches WildFly (Java / Jakarta EE server) but seems inaccessible via browser

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, aws-ec2, wildfly

I am trying to setup AWS for a JBoss WildFly 31.0.0.Final to get a demo webapp up and running. So I found this tutorial:

https://kamalmeet.com/cloud-computing/amazon-ec2-step-by-step-guide-to-setup-a-java-application/

I created a ubuntu instance, along with a keypair set to read-only and manually changed some properties for the PEM file on my local Windows 11 machine. I then connected to my Ubuntu instance with my SSH shell as AWS default user named `ubuntu`.

I ended up with:

---

[image]

---

(*I know it might not be the smartest move to post this screenshot, but for the sake of this question, I will repeat the whole process once this gets solved...*)

So, I then pretty much copy-pasted the commands listed in the tutorial, with some "minor" adjustments like `apt upgrade` and the installation of Java 17 + JDK 17:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk openjdk-17-jre
```

Here I issued `java -version` saying:

```
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Now add user and group `wildfly`:

```
sudo groupadd -r wildfly
sudo useradd -r -g wildfly -d /opt/wildfly -s /sbin/nologin wildfly
```

Grab the latest WildFly, unzip/untar it, put it into `/opt/` and create a symlink into `/opt/wildfly/` to point to the actual dir.

```
wget https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/releases/download/31.0.0.Final/wildfly-31.0.0.Final.tar.gz -P /tmp
sudo tar xf /tmp/wildfly-31.0.0.Final.tar.gz -C /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/wildfly-31.0.0.Final /opt/wildfly
sudo chown -RH wildfly: /opt/wildfly
```

Now create a dir where the WildFly config `wildfly.conf` is placed:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/wildfly

sudo cp /opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/wildfly.conf /etc/wildfly/
sudo nano /etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
```

The file `wildfly.conf` you never needed or even noticed during development on your local machine looks like this:

```
# The configuration you want to run
WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone.xml

# The mode you want to run
WILDFLY_MODE=standalone

# The address to bind to
WILDFLY_BIND=0.0.0.0
```

I wondered what to edit here. I left it as is, making the `standalone.xml` being used. Bind address: IIRC `0.0.0.0` is the broadcast address, so WildFly accepts requests from anywhere in the world (??).

Now copy the file `launch.sh` to the WildFly `bin` dir and make all `*.sh` scripts there executable:

```
sudo cp /opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/launch.sh /opt/wildfly/bin/
sudo sh -c "chmod +x /opt/wildfly/bin/*.sh"
```

The file `launch.sh` looks like this:

```
if [ "x$WILDFLY_HOME" = "x" ]; then
    WILDFLY_HOME="/opt/wildfly"
fi

if [[ "$1" == "domain" ]]; then
    $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/domain.sh -c $2 -b $3
else
    $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c $2 -b $3
fi
```

That WildFly contrib script pretty much looks for the `WILDFLY_HOME` env var and if it is not set, assume `/opt/wildfly` as home, resulting in `/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh` being executed when `launch.sh` is.

Now config the launcher (note, I have absolutely basic Ubuntu knowledge). From what I read, the dir `/etc/systemd/system/` in Ubuntu is a more modern approach where to manage the services and sessions (to get rid of the rather old-fashioned `init.d` stuff AFAI understand). So we copy another WildFly contrib script to `/etc/systemd/system/`:

```
sudo cp /opt/wildfly/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/wildfly.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

The `wildfly.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
User=wildfly
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So here you can see that this service file picks up the config from `/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf` and that it actually executes `/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh` (this is where other env vars come into place that haven't been set at all).

The next command seem to tell Ubuntu to reload the service config (deamons) and start + enable JBoss WildFly:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start wildfly
sudo systemctl enable wildfly
```

Issuing a final `sudo systemctl status wildfly` gives:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-16:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-16:~$ sudo systemctl start wildfly
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-16:~$ sudo systemctl enable wildfly
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-16:~$ sudo systemctl status wildfly
● wildfly.service - The WildFly Application Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-02-05 10:19:39 UTC; 16s ago
   Main PID: 22971 (launch.sh)
      Tasks: 127 (limit: 1121)
     Memory: 386.1M
        CPU: 15.964s
     CGroup: /system.slice/wildfly.service
             ├─22971 /bin/bash /opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh standalone standalone.xml 0.0.0.0
             ├─22972 /bin/sh /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -b 0.0.0.0
             └─23093 java "-D[Standalone]" "-Djdk.serialFilter=maxbytes=10485760;maxdepth=128;maxarray=100000;maxrefs=300000" -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:Metaspac>
```

The last command is:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
```

It's called "Uncomplicated Firewall" and seems like it is installed on most Ubuntu and Debian systems. It obviously opens port 8080 to the outside world.

**QUESTION:**

Whatever I do after all this, opening a browser to the public IP given + port, I simply cannot access the WildFly I just set up:

[image]

The above error message means "The connection has timed out".

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is AWS blocking port 8080 from outside? Is using HTTP disallowed at all?

Comment: What do you need ufw for? Why noe to use AWS security group instead?

Comment: Hmm. I tried this. I noticed this in the AWS console, but the UI won't let me add 8080 as port. This didn't work, but does now. I feel really stupid. THANKS. Please post this as an answer: add port to Security Group -> tab `Inbound rules` -> `Edit inbound rules` -> and `Add rule` use Type `Custom TCP` + Port range `8080` + `Anywhere IPv4` or use CIDR `0.0.0.0/0` and restart the instance.

Comment: AWS doesn't restrict protocols. Most likely you've got something not set up correctly. Common things would be a security group rule or NACL blocking access, no internet gateway, subnet not routed correctly, etc. Try connecting to port 8080 from the instance, if that works then it's AWS infrastructure rather than instance settings. You would have to post more detail for more help, security groups, NACLs, subnets, routing, etc.